# How do i know if emails are enabled in my organization via SOQL or API?

Tags: soql, email, api

I'm currently showing the user's email configuration in my application. However none of this matters if my organization has disabled emails. i have to know if that is true before showing the user his configuration options. I tried looking up the Organization Object but it doesn't seem to have that field. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The [EmailAdministrationSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailadministrationsettings.htm) object in the Metadata API should be a good starting point.  The docs say it "[r]epresents an organization’s email administration settings, **including email deliverability**,..." but not seeing a field immediately that seems to correspond to the "**Access level**" dropdown in **Setup > Email > Deliverability**.

Comment: @Bow-chicawow-ers exactly. I've looked into that and i seem to find the equivalent fields inside certain objects but i can't seem to find the field that references that exact field enabling email notifications organization wide.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same long back ago, I couldn't find a solution for this.
So i went with a solution of adding try/catch blocks, and checking in catch if exception contains so and so, i'm letting the user with a custom message. 
Though its not a viable solution, but i don't see anything other than this

Comment: I too am struggling with this. Thanks for your answer mate., will take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way is to retrieve the page content of *Email Deliverability* using `PageReference.getContent()` and parse it using regular expression.

For example:

```java
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/email-admin/editOrgEmailSettings.apexp');
String htmlBody = pr.getContent().toString().replace('\n','');
Matcher pm = Pattern.compile('sendEmailAccessControlSelect.+?>\\s*<option.+?"selected">(.+?)</option>').matcher(htmlBody);
String accessLevel;
if (pm.find() && pm.groupCount() > 0) {
    accessLevel= pm.group(1);
}
```

This would work as long as the page content is unchanged.